# Is there an #ifdef stripping C/C++ utility

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

Is there a utility that can strip out say `#ifdef PRO_VERSION ... #endif` code?

Please don't tell me about the Visual Studio compiler flag or XCode's view post-processed source.  I can't automate it conveniently like, say, a console application.

What I am looking to do here is find an existing utility if it exists.  If not ... I guess I'll have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Why won't looking at preprocessed source work?  You could do that from the command line, right?

Comment: A preprocessed source has all the .h header stuff in it!  Like 100,000 lines of code from <windows.h> or equivalent and <stdio.h> and <math.h> yada yada yada.

Comment: @ hyde ... it may be dup.  I'm playing with sunifdef right now, my initial search attempts here didn't yield anything.  Go figure ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[unifdef](http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/) might be what you're looking for.

From [its manual](http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/unifdef.txt):

> The unifdef utility acts on #if, #ifdef, #ifndef, #elif, #else, and
>        #endif lines.  A directive is only processed if the symbols specified on
>        the command line are sufficient to allow unifdef to get a definite value
>        for its control expression.  If the result is false, the directive and
>        the following lines under its control are removed.  If the result is
>        true, only the directive is removed.  An #ifdef or #ifndef directive is
>        passed through unchanged if its controlling symbol is not specified on
>        the command line.  Any #if or #elif control expression that has an
>        unknown value or that unifdef cannot parse is passed through unchanged.